# Access MySQL via HTTP

Tags: mysql, http

Is there any working solution for MySQL to be able to request data directly via HTTP/jsonp way?

I need to provide ready SQL statement to the server.

Something with SQL-templates etc.

Comment: Do you mean: http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html?

Comment: Do you mean something like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)?

Comment: I need something like CouchDB http access. Picking data right from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: I need something like CouchDB http access. Picking data right from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There is beta version of mysql 5.7 that does that

[MySql experimental MySQL HTTP API](http://ilyabylich.svbtle.com/experimental-mysql-http-api-and-ruby)

I am currently trying the following alternatives:

[YOG-Sql Tunnel in PHP](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/410502) and

Others: (1) undergo writing some webservices (java - php - c), (2) use 'mysql proxy' or 'mysql tunnel' (3) Code everyhing in gcc and run a proxy as http.

Tried many, stayed with YogSQL Tunnel (lot easier) - BTW ALL THOSE DID NOT GAVE SAME REAL-TIME RESULTS AS EVERYTHING INSIDE THE SAME DATACENTER (2 servers) or a gigabit network (250k - 500k records/second). So, latency may be a killer on one's ubiquitous cloud computing.

Comment: what did he means by 'request data' - request to the mysql server and return html-json or request something else further ?

Answer (score 1):

[I tried NGINX http add-on modules](https://github.com/arut/nginx-mysql-module)

ngnix really rocks, on static html even amazon free was outstanding (1ms wait) on 3000 requests/sec. Specific SQL modules, whatsoever, may be memory-consumig if goes heavy loader.io.